# Wrong selection from the database

Tags: sql

Requires user1 and user2 to be displayed, instead are displayed user5 and user1.
I used `DBIC_TRACE = 1` to track the queries generated by SQL and the result is:

```
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user1' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user2' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user3' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:29', '2019-10-29T07:43:29', 'user4' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level1', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user5' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user6' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user7' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user8' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user9' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user10' 
INSERT INTO user_access_rights ( access_rights_id, date_begin, date_end, username) 
    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
    RETURNING id: 'level2', '2019-10-28T07:43:30', '2019-10-29T07:43:30', 'user11'

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM user_access_rights me 
WHERE ( ( access_rights_id = ? AND date_end >= ? ) ): 'level1', '2019-10-28 07:43:30+0000' 

SELECT access_rights_recipient.username, access_rights_recipient.last_login, me.access_rights_id 
FROM user_access_rights me 
JOIN users access_rights_recipient ON access_rights_recipient.username = me.username 
WHERE ( ( access_rights_id = ? AND date_end >= ? ) ) 
ORDER BY date_begin DESC, username ASC LIMIT ?: 'level1', '2019-10-28 07:43:30+0000', '2'
```

May anyone explain to me why this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The `date_end` value for the record with `level1` and `user2` is `2019-10-29T07:43:29`, just ***before*** the limit in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!But I noticed that the date_end value in the query is 2019-10-28 07:43:30+0000.May you give me more details ? Because it is flaky answer, sometimes i get the right answer somtimes I don't. E.g: I run again and is shown user4 and user5.Thank you!